# Workflows in 2013 and 2010 can not change a library column with IRM enabled

Tags: list, designer-workflow, irm

I am using SharePoint Online,

I'm trying, via workflow, define a column of text in a library that is enabled with IRM and demanding check out to edit a document.

However, the flow can only update the column when IRM is disabled and do not require checkout to edit the document. The features of MRI and Check In / Check Out is mandatory in this case. Even making the check out in the workflow, does not update the column reaches to other features, not define the column in the current item.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: You are doing Check out item, update field, check in item in the workflow correct? You can also try putting that in an impersonation step.

Comment: Yes, I do ckeck out, update and do Checkin but not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered that caused it.

In the IRM configuration exists the option "Do not allow users to upload documents do not support IRM", by checking this option multiple workflow features stop working.

It does not make much sense, but was it that caused the error :(